# Условия в python

Tags: python, if, условия

У меня есть 4 переменных, они содержат цену продукта (1000р,1500,2000,5000) нужно написав лишь ОДИН if вывести через принт сообщение со скидкой, например, если товар стоит 1000р то скидка 2%, если 1500 то 3%, если 2000 то 4%, если 5000 то 5%. На вас, дорогие разработчике вся моя надежда не получить 2 по информатике в семестре

Comment: А если бы было две переменных, смогли бы написать?

Comment: нет, остается верить лишь в могучую силу stack ove flow

Comment: на этом сайте не решают за вас, а только помогают, полное решение вам никто не напишет

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку решения.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Такой вариант решения должен подойти

```
a = 1000
b = 1500
c = 2000
d = 5000
f = input("Цена продукта")
for w,q in enumerate([a,b,c,d]):
    if int(f) == q:
        print(int(f) - int(f)/100*(w+1))
```

Comment: СПАСИБООО!!! А ТО Я ГОЛОВУ УЖЕ СЛОМАЛ!!!

Comment: @Евгений можете ответ галочкой отметить?